# Application has 2 static variable scopes

Tags: c++, static, scope, singleton

As this post became much larger than it should have been, I have started again.

My problem is that for some reson, part of my c++ project is being automatically compiled into a shared library, and therefore no longer shares static scope with the rest of my codebase.

I have isolated the cause of this, but still dont understand why it would happen.

I am integrating a 3rd party shared library into my project, which requires me to add some classes to my project also.

If I only link to the library and include the headers, my project outputs an exe file, and everything is peachy.

The second that I add:

(CAkFilePackageLowLevelIOBlocking is one of the classes I was required to add via cpp code to my project)

```
protected:
  CAkFilePackageLowLevelIOBlocking m_LowLevelIO;
```

to my SoundManager class, then build, I get this extra line at the end telling me its outputting a .lib and .exp file:

```
1>  Generating Code...
1>     Creating library D:\DustCloud\WorkingCopy\src\VS2010\Debug\GameDbg.lib and object D:\DustCloud\WorkingCopy\src\VS2010\Debug\GameDbg.exp
1>  VS2010.vcxproj -> D:\DustCloud\WorkingCopy\src\VS2010\Debug\GameDbg.exe
```

So, to post a much simpler question,

What could be causing my project to need to build a .lib file simply by adding a class member of a type given to me by a library?

Could this be a pragma def or something similar somewhere in those classes that forces .lib output?

I am using VS2010 and building a plain old win32 c++ application

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by `the map has split` - if you declare one map in your code, it cannot split. Can you show some code to illustrate?

Comment: I seem to remember that globals and hence singletons are defined per shared library, so yes, if classes are registered in the library, they will be in a separate singleton.  (no answer, because I'm not sure)

Comment: @stefaanv - I'm sure that's exactly the answer

Comment: I am 90% sure this is the cause, what I need help with is why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

After lots of barking up the wrong tree, I have discovered that my problem had nothing to do with shared library or scope. The problem was being caused by the static initialization of the map which I put in the top of the CPP file to avoid an unresolved external

```
CBaseFactory::map_type* CBaseFactory::map = new map_type()
```

Was obviously creating a new instance of the map...

The CBaseFactory also tried to instanciate the map on first use if it was NULL

```
static map_type * getMap() {
    if(!map) 
    { 
      map = new map_type; 
    } 
    return map; 
}
```

The obvious problem here is if the initialization code at the top of the factory cpp file doesnt get executed first, whatever was added before that will be cleared.

The reason this has not presented itself before is a complete coincidence of naming conventions, that this factory was defined in ComponentBase.h which was aphabetically the first code file execute the static initialization, therefore nothing got cleared.

Once I added ComponentAudio, ComponentAudioCharacter(both coincidently come before ComponentBase aphabetically) and therefore was registered in the map before the map was overriden.

So it seems the shared library output has absolutely nothing to do with this.

Simply chaing the initialization line to

```
CBaseFactory::map_type* CBaseFactory::map = CBaseFactory::map;
```

Doesnt modify the map and causes the template to be compiled correctly.

Not sure how, but hopefully this helps someone.